# Javascript set Interval is running more then one time in single second

Tags: javascript, face-api

I am writing a code where A video will play and then through faceapi we will catch the emotion of the user every second so far every thing we going good
As soon as I added one validation that if face is not detectable for 5 seconds it will pause the video and stop the camera until user play it again after adding this validation my code is running 3 times in a second.

I am attaching screenshot and code also

1. screenshot if video is normally running it will check after every single second[here are the normal results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzb3M.png)
2. [Alert for user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDdZA.png)r which will come and pause the video
3. Result after no detections [you can see now its running multiple time in single second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeqvB.png)

below is the code

```
var nofacefound = 0;
    let videotempid = videotags[1];
    var titleofvideo = videotags[1].title;
    videotempid.addEventListener('play', ()=> {
        if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then(function(stream) {
            camarea.srcObject = stream;
            camarea.play();
            });
        }
    });
    camarea.addEventListener('play', () => {
       setInterval(async() => {
           // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
           const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(camarea, new         faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceExpressions();
           if(detections.length == 1) {
               //copying the array
               const expression = detections[0].expressions;
               //sorting the array
               const predictedemotion =   Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(expression).sort(([,a],[,b]) => b-a)
               );
               var emotionstate = Object.keys(predictedemotion)[0];
               var secondemotion = Object.keys(predictedemotion)[1];
               console.log(secondemotion);
                var vidtimestamp = videotempid.currentTime;
                var courseid = document.getElementById('courseid').innerHTML;
                var tempdata = {"courseid":courseid,
                 "Video Title": titleofvideo,
                 "video time stamp": vidtimestamp,
                 "Emotion": emotionstate,
               };
               console.log(tempdata);
             } else {
               nofacefound = ++nofacefound;
               if(nofacefound > 4)
               {
                   videotempid.pause();
                   window.alert("we are unable to find your face please check your camera or adjust your position");
                   nofacefound = 0;
                   camarea.srcObject = null;
              }
          }
       },1000);
    });

    videotempid.addEventListener('pause', ()=>{
        camarea.srcObject = null;
    });`
```

How I can run this code only one time per second or like If 5 seconds face is not detectable it will pause but as soon as use will play the video it will just run every single second. If I remove this 5 second detection validation then its working fine

Comment: The `setInterval()` function sets up a timer that fires over and over again. Every time it is called, **another** timer is started.

Comment: Think about what happens if you get more than one "play" event. The timer started on the first "play" will still be running.

Comment: When you call `setInterval()` the callback function is called 1 second later, then the second after that, and the second after that, forever. When you start another one, it will do the same thing. Your code should be saving the returned identifier from `setInterval()` and cancelling the previous timer before starting a new one.

Comment: Thanks Pointy I understood and it works very well